# statefulset roling update effects high availibility

Tags: kubernetes, statefulset

Any way in kubernetes to first deploy a new pod with a new version, then take down the updated pod and add the one we created in advance to the statefulset ?When some pod gets recreated during rolling update it can take a lot of time and the app can be unavailable since it needs quorum for example.

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your question. I think you’re asking how to deploy your app without downtime. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, say I have 3 nodes in my cluster - each with 1 pod - >If I could start a 4th pod "on the side" and switch to it I would save myself the starting time of the upgraded pod